# Problem with get a image with get Request axios

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, axios

I have a problem to get a image, but I don't know if the problem is on `put` or on `get`.

Context: I'm building an aplicattion that I can take a photo and send this photo with the `put` for an image base with one code bar, when I send this image I should be able to see this image inside a `div`, but when I send, this image goes in a weird way if you search what was sent by the API. Anybody help?

I will show the code and the image that show when I search the api.

code:

```
//this is the put

 const content = this.foto1;

  const send = async (url) => {
    return await api
      .put(url, content, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log("error");
        }
      });
  };



 //this is the get
 
  async getRequest() {
  const image = async (url) => {
    return await api
      .get(url, {
        responseType: "blob",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      })
      .then(
        (response) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
          })
      );
```

[IMAGE REQUEST PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS3gR.png)

And this is a image that shows for me when I search the requisition in a url.
Please, I need a help hahahaha
How can I do this? I want that image show correctly to me.

[image: Cbroe, this is my application]

Comment: It is quite hard to understand your problem description. _"send this photo with the put for an image base with one code bar"_ - no clue what that is supposed to mean. _"but when I send, this image goes in a weird way if you search what was sent by the API"_ - also, no idea.

Comment: basically this is a get and put with image, when i do the get, its work, but when i do the put, don't work, a blank image appears where I want to upload with the image that i did the put.

Comment: "Don't work" also doesn't work for us, as an actual problem description. _We_ are not sitting in front of this system so that we could debug and investigate further details, only you do. You need to give us something better than "doesn't work."

Comment: I'll edit the post and add the image, but it's true, we would have to debug together for you to understand the problem, it's hard to explain in words.

Comment: Look the post, i put the image.

Comment: I set a image with put, right? but when i do the get, appears this a blank image appears for me.

Comment: And what have you configured on the server side to _process_ this PUT request ...?

Comment: i don't have access on the server side... xD Just my boss